# javascript for time between two different inputs

Tags: javascript, datetime

Say I wanted to define a function "start" and a function "stop", and I wanted to output as accurately as possible the real time between the two functions getting called? The time elapsed will probably be in microseconds.

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: Nothing, really - not really the javascript maven

Comment: @jamesson you will find that people generally aren't going to give you an answer if you've made no attempt at it yourself. It's a bit like a washing machine, you get out what you put in. If you put no effort into finding a solution it's unlikely you will get much effort in the response.

Comment: You don't need to be a maven to do this. Start with learning the basics, put together a working example that includes the JavaScript and HTML (if any), and if you get stuck, ask a question providing what you have so for.

Comment: @GreenDay: Please do not link to w3schools. It contains [outdated, incomplete, misguided, and just plain incorrect information](http://www.w3fools.com).

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker noted, however it contained the information required to solve the question and took me all of 2 seconds to find on google which is the least the OP could have done....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create new Date objects at the beginning of each method.  Use the `getTime()` method to get the milliseconds value for the date.  Subtract the `start` value from the `end` value.  That is the difference, in milliseconds.

I'm not aware of any general way of getting better than millisecond time resolution in browser side javascript.

Answer (score 1):

The manual, old fashioned way is:

```
var a = new Date();

// do stuff

var b = new Date();

console.log("stuff took:", b.getTime() - a.getTime());
```

If you're in a modern Chrome, you can use the console's support for this:

```
console.time('stuff');

// do stuff

console.timeEnd('stuff');
```

And it will print the time for you.

Answer (score 0):

The `Date` object has a granularity of milliseconds only so the best you can do is that.

```
var Host = {
    start : function() {
        this.time = new DateTime().getTime();
        //method
    },
    stop : function() { 
        this.diff = this.time - new DateTIme().getTime();
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The most accurate method I can think of would be to use

```
setTimeout(function2, offset)
function1();
```

In this instance the order is set so that the timer is absolute in that it starting the timer is the entry point

```
function1();
setTimeout(function2, offset)
```

In this instance the start point of the timer is relative to the completion of the first function.